# events.js:292 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, redis

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (D:\discordjs\node_modules\redis\index.js:341:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\discordjs\node_modules\redis\index.js:222:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

well im having this error after some time of my discordbot running im using redis to store my mute command archives

Comment: Can you show a relevant part or your code? which libraries are you importing?